# Appending Anchor tag to jQuery Mobile Header not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, markup, jquery-mobile-button

I would currently like to dynamically add an anchor to a `data-role = "header"` div. I currently have the following code:

HTML

```
<div data-role ="header">
     <div  id="SignUp"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#SignUp').append('<a data-icon="star" href="#" data-role="button" id="SignUpLink">Sign Up</a>');
$("#SignUpLink").trigger('create');
```

The problem I am having is that the it's not producing the following:

[image]

But rather the code found [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9sxV/). I've tried to refresh the `SignUpLink` with `.trigger()` and `.button('refresh')`. But that also doesn't seem to work. I'm not really not sure how to fix the problem found in the jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AtKhs/

When appending content to page header or footer another function must be used.

```
.trigger('pagecreate');
```

Unlike **trigger('create')** which enhances only content, **trigger('pagecreate')** will try to enhance everything.

Read more about it in my blog article **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, look for a chapter called: **Enhance a full page content**. Working example can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved much more easily this way: swapping .trigger("create") place:

```
$('#SignUp').append('<a data-icon="star" href="#" data-role="button" id="SignUpLink">Sign Up</a>').trigger('create');
```

test and see which will work perfectly and save lines of code.

with this you eliminate the second line

```
$("#SignUpLink").trigger('create');
```